# How to check that systemtime on web server is configured OR not?

Tags: twitter, webserver, ntp

How do I check that system time is configured OR not correctly on the web host server? I need to check its sync with twitter server time. How do I do that? I checked by running `"strftime('%c')"` on web server that its time is either -7 hours OR +5 different hours my systemtime.

EDIT

OK, I checked time zone as Piskvor mentioned & Web server has 'UTC/GMT -5 hours' while my system is in 'UTC/GMT +2 hours'. my problem is that I need to sure the clock on the server is properly synced with NTP. How do I do that ?
I am using Windows XP.

Comment: Did you consider that the server could be in a different TZ than you are? Check its timezone settings, too.

Comment: @Piskvor, yes, it is like that. Web server has 'UTC/GMT -5 hours' while my system is in 'UTC/GMT +2 hours'. OK, my problem is that I need to sure the clock on the server is properly synced with NTP. How do I do that ?

Comment: @XCeptable: The *server* is running Windows XP? Strange. The server's OS is relevant for the accuracy check here. Also note that for the best synchronisation, you should use the same NTP server as the server.

Comment: @Piskvor, no, server is using Linux. I said I am using xp on my computer. Actually my question is how to check that the clock on the web server is properly synced with NTP. I am not looking for a solution to synchronize my systemtime. I think xp system time is already sync with a time server. If I check like: DB-click on time in lower right task-bar on xp desktop->Click on internet time tab, it shows time server system is sync with.

Comment: @XCeptable: See @Matthew Wilson's answer then - that's the way to check NTP clock sources in Linux - you'll need to run the command *on your server*. Also see the server's system log `/var/log/messages` or the like; there should be messages from `ntpd` indicating the results of previous synchronizations.

Comment: As for the time in WinXP, you are quite correct. I have thought you wanted to have the clock of your computer as close to the server as possible.

Comment: @Piskvor, but how can I run this command on server. I can see 'control panel' of the web server that provides tabs to see manage account, email, database, FTP, Domains, Site, DNS management, software & services, and statistics.

Comment: @XCeptable: If you don't have shell access, you'd need to ask your hosting provider to check it for you :(

Answer (score 1):

```
ntpq -p
```

You should see a list of your configured clock sources, with "*" indicating a clock source selected as the source for synchronisation.